# How to get text between different tags in Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have to parse html code like this:

```
  <td><b>Dont need it</b>I need this!!<br><b>Dont need it too:</b> I need 
  this too!!<br> <b>Text:</b> I need this<br></td>
```

I tried something like this:

**td.select("< b />< br >)") but It had trown an exception.**

I am able to get the text in b tag, but how can I get text between  b and br tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get all the text nodes under the `<td/>` but none of the named nodes. JSoup has a method called `textNodes()` that returns these:

```
Element td = ...;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (TextNode textNode : td.textNodes()) {
    sb.append(textNode.text());
}
return sb.toString();
```